# Why is Firefox showing me a cached version of a page

Tags: html, apache, http, caching, iframe

I have a page the includes an iframe.…

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- … -->
    <iframe
        src="/assets/js/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=2021-09-12_1200-file.pdf#zoom=page-width"
        style="..."
    ></iframe>
    <!-- … -->
  </body>
</html>
```

That includes the following response headers…

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 26 Oct 2021 11:02:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.27
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
X-DEBUGKIT-ID: 77761443-2882-4882-b0e1-01eea68deded
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 2349
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

If I change the file path in the iframe src attribute (e.g `/assets/js/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=2021-10-26_1200-file.pdf#zoom=page-width` - note the new timestamp), and reload the page, the old file is still returned, rather than the new one, despite the `Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate` header.

Debugging the requests recevied by the server, I can see…

1. The parent page is requested and returned with the headers as above (with new `Date` & `X-DEBUGKIT-ID` header values), and the correct, updated iframe src value.
2. The iframe page is being requested with the original filename, rather than the new one (I'm assuming from the cached page).

If I reload using Cmd+Shift+R (to ignore the browser cache), then the correct iframe document is loaded.

What am I missing in this setup that is causing the page to be cached?  I thought that the `Cache-Control` header we have should be sufficient here.

If I add a random query string to the parent page this correctly loads new documents, but I feel this is a hack that should not be needed.

I've also tried adding a `Etag` header containing a random string that's different for each request, but this seems to have no effect on the browser caching.

Comment: The first thing I would try is not using reload. Reloads are not like regular page loads, and browsers follow different and nonstandard rules about what assets to load. What happens when you open the same URL in a different tab or window?

Comment: Ah ha!  Thank you @KevinChristopherHenry.  That works when I open it in a new (non-icognito) tab.